# Secure REST Controller through the Roles/Authorities

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I don't understand really the logics of the **roles/authorities** in Spring Security using Spring Boot (despite the documentation).

I would authorise the mapped controller requests according to the logged user.

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

General idea is very easy: you have role in your application, you have a users. Users have the collection of roles(may be empty). Also, all endpoints of you application(controller methods, service methods) can be allowed to reach only for some sets of this roles(see @RolesAllowed annotation). If you try to reach this method(via http request, for example) and you(as user) haven't this roles, you would be banned to get valid response instead you will receive 403 error

Comment: Thank you Sobik. But I don't understand how to create the login and "authorize" a role. Should I create an "Authorization" object in the entity user?

Comment: Andreas, please, look at this class :http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html. You authentication object is implementation of this interface. And this interface contains method getAuthorities(). If you, for example(i don't know details of you implementation, so I just guess), stores you Users in database, you should create your Implementation of UserDetailsService with method UserDetails loadByUserName(String userName). In this method you can define Authorities for you UserDetails according to you logic

Comment: Provide me you spring-security.xml or SecurityConfig class, and I will have opprotunity to help you in details

Comment: I don't use xml configuration, but annotations. My problem is how to assign a role to an user.

Comment: U can store them in database, please, view one of my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40933970/2322770

Comment: Thank you for your time. The answer you commented didn't help me. I would simply to do a login for an user without formlogin (html/jsp). I want a rest controller where after my db query, I can add a role for an user in order to be able to use @PreAuthorize to authorize the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following as a reference to add spring security in a rest based application. I hope this helps others as well..
http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

There is a link with sample code to take inspiration.

The idea being in rest we don't redirect and disable these redirections for login and provide alternatives HTTP responses.